# What is the proper way to write a SQL statement using GROUP BY to achieve a single row for each 'group'?

Tags: sql, group-by

Given the following table structure in MS SQL:

Data:

```
ID-----+EventDate-------------------+IP--------------+Count
1       2013-03-20 21:15:22.113 192.168.1.1      False
4       2013-03-21 21:15:22.113 192.168.1.1      True
5       2013-03-19 21:15:22.113 192.168.1.1      True
6       2013-03-19 21:15:22.113 192.168.1.1      False
7       2013-03-21 21:15:22.113 192.168.1.1      True
8       2013-03-19 21:15:22.113 192.168.1.1      True
```

I want to write a query that returns one line, for each unique IP address, with the first instance of the lowest date as "MinDate" and the last instance of the date (most recent) as max date, with a count where it's "TRUE" ignoring the false count records.

Is googling group by, and assuming to use min() and max() for the date expressions the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work using `GROUP BY` IP.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) cnt,
   MIN(EventDate) MinEventDate,
   MAX(EventDate) MaxEventDate,
   IP
FROM YourTable
WHERE Count = 'True'
GROUP BY IP
```

Which RDBMS are you using -- `COUNT` as a column name might be reserved.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/984ea/1)